# Jquery.flot - Android 4.2.2 WebKit 534.30 creates a second graph on the page

Tags: android, webkit, flot

I have a jquery flot with filtering buttons below the graphic , which enable user to show the values on a weekly manner, or daily manner and so on. 
The problem happens when the user clicks a filtering button, suddenly another flot chart above the first chart is created and it stays there till I leave the page and come back to the page.

I have the following code to show a graph as soon as user gets to the page ; 
And the filtering button calls a function that has the same piece of code but with a different tick size (with week for example).

PS: I'm using Phonegap that prepares the app for the normal Android webview. The engine used depends on the Android version.

**WebKit versions;** [Ref](http://http:%20%20%20//jimbergman.net/webkit-version-in-android-version/)

- Android 4.2.2    534.30  ( Another flot chart is created)
- Android 4.4.x    537.36  ( Works as expected )

Code:

```
var plot = $.plot("#placeholder", [{
                data: dAlle
            }], {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true,
                    markings: [{
                        yaxis: {
                            from: 0,
                            to: 12
                        },
                        color: "#F2CDEA"
                    }, {
                        yaxis: {
                            from: rangeMin,
                            to: rangeMax
                        },
                        color: "#D7EEE1"
                    }]
                },
                xaxis: {
                    mode: "time",
                    minTickSize: [1, "month"],
                    /*min: theVeryFirstPoint,
                    max: theVeryLastPoint*/
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 12
                }
            });
```

The weird thing is that same logic works for Android with LG G2 API level 19 (4.4.2), but when I install the app into Samsung S2 with API Level 16 (4.2.2) , this problem occurs. Is there any way of preventing it from occuring?

CSS + JS imports are as follows ;

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/main.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jqm-icon-pack-fa.css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>

<script src="js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>

<link href="css/examples.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.threshold.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.time.js"></script>
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript" src="js/flot/jquery.flot.areamarkings.js"></script>
```

**Filter function that is called ;**

```
   $("#a-uke").click(function() {
                  console.log("a dag filtering will be applied...");


            var newDataSer = window.localStorage.getItem("storedData");
            if (newDataSer != null) {
                newDataSer = JSON.parse(newDataSer);

                // Just convert into a new array object for the FIRST time
                //if (dagButtonClicked == false) {
                $.each(newDataSer, function(index, datapoint) {
                    datapoint[2] = datapoint[0];
                    datapoint[0] = (new Date(datapoint[0])).getHours();
                    console.log("hours created : " + datapoint[0]);
                    dagButtonClicked = true;
                });
                //}
                if (newDataSer != null && newDataSer.length > 0) {
                    newDataSer.sort(function(x, y) {
                        console.log("sorting..");
                        return x[0] - y[0];
                    })
                }
            } else
                newDataSer = [];



            $.plot("#placeholder", [newDataSer], {
                series: {
                    lines: {
                        show: true
                    },
                    points: {
                        show: true
                    }
                },
                grid: {
                    hoverable: true,
                    clickable: true,
                    areaMarkings: [{
                        points: [
                            [7, 12],
                            [24, 12],
                            [24, 0],
                            [7, 0]
                        ],
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#F2CDEA"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [7, rangeBr1],
                            [7, rangeBr2],
                            [10, rangeBr2],
                            [10, rangeBr1]
                        ], // Green for breakfast
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#D7EEE1"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [7, rangeBr2],
                            [7, rangeBr3],
                            [10, rangeBr3],
                            [10, rangeBr2]
                        ], // Gradient1 Top for breakfast
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#DFE4E3"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [7, rangeBr3],
                            [7, rangeBr4],
                            [10, rangeBr4],
                            [10, rangeBr3]
                        ], // Gradient2 Top for breakfast
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#E7DAE6"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [7, rangeBrBot2],
                            [7, rangeBrBot3],
                            [10, rangeBrBot3],
                            [10, rangeBrBot2]
                        ], // Gradient1 Bottom for breakfast
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#DFE4E3"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [7, rangeBrBot1],

                            [7, rangeBrBot2],
                            [10, rangeBrBot2],
                            [10, rangeBrBot1]
                        ], // Gradient2 Bottom for breakfast
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#E7DAE6"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [10, rangeMin],
                            [10, rangeMaxGrad],
                            [24, rangeMaxGrad],
                            [24, rangeMin]
                        ], // Green for the rest
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#D7EEE1"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [10, rangeMaxGrad],
                            [10, rangeMaxGrad2],
                            [24, rangeMaxGrad2],
                            [24, rangeMaxGrad]
                        ], // Gradient1 top for the rest
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#DFE4E3"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [10, rangeMaxGrad2],
                            [10, rangeMaxGrad3],
                            [24, rangeMaxGrad3],
                            [24, rangeMaxGrad2]
                        ], // Gradient2 top for the rest
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#E7DAE6"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [10, rangeMinGrad2],
                            [10, rangeMin],
                            [24, rangeMin],
                            [24, rangeMinGrad2]
                        ], // Gradient1 bottom for the rest
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#DFE4E3"
                    }, {
                        points: [
                            [10, rangeMinGrad3],
                            [10, rangeMinGrad2],
                            [24, rangeMinGrad2],
                            [24, rangeMinGrad3]
                        ], // Gradient2 bottom for the rest
                        lineWidth: 0,
                        fillColor: "#E7DAE6"
                    }]
                },
                xaxis: {
                    tickFormatter: getAmPmHour,
                    min: 7,
                    max: 24
                },
                yaxis: {
                    min: 0,
                    max: 12
                }
            });

        });
```

Comment: You should add the code for the button click event. And is this really an app or a html+js (web) page in the browser (which browsers have your phones)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what is causing that bug, but there are two possible solutions you can try:

1) You can clear the old plot before creating the new one:

```
$('#placeholder').empty();
$.plot("#placeholder", [newDataSer], { /* your new options */ });
```

2) You can use the existing plot instead of creating a new one (which is the recommended way):

```
plot.setData([newDataSer]);
plot.getOptions().grid.areaMarkings = [ /* your new markings / options */ ];
plot.getOptions().xaxis = { /* your new options */ };
plot.setupGrid();
plot.draw();
```

Comment: Raidri, Solution 1 worked. But I prefered using the second one as you suggested.  However,  when I apply that and put the grid options with plot.getOptions().grid = { /* your new options */ };    I lose the markings.  Any suggestion how to keep markings as well ?

Comment: You can change the properties of `grid` directly, like `plot.getOptions().grid.areamarkings = { ... }` and leave the `grid.markings`.

Comment: plot.getOptions().grid.areamarkings = {yaxis: {
                                from: 0,
                                to: 12
                            },
                            color: "#F2CDEA"
                        };   did not work either.

Comment: The following simply is not working ;  Am I doing something wrong ? 


plot.getOptions().grid.areamarkings = [{
                    points: [
                        [7, 12],
                        [24, 12],
                        [24, 0],
                        [7, 0]
                    ],
                    lineWidth: 0,
                    fillColor: "#F2CDEA"
                }];

Comment: It should be `areaMarkings` with a capital `M`. If it still doesn't work, could you create a [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net) or code snippet based on your code for easier debugging?